# Handling Confirmation dialog box in java

Tags: java

My problem is: I want to catch/handle dialog box Returned by other Application in java.

Actually automating input sheet creation from java. Input sheet are in excel sheet. Macros are used to generate xml.

Solution: I have used Vb script calling Macro from Automation suite.

Hurdle: It throws Confirmation dialog box. and then File Save dialog box. I want to automate both the process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing, but I cheat : I have a Java application that needs to read data from a legacy application. Using something called AutoIt - http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ - I've managed to get both working as expected.

That might be your best bet.

Comment: I've used the same myself, and it works great. Why? Because this tool was built to do just this. Also, it's not too hard to integrate AutoIt with Java if need be. 1+ up-vote for a good answer.

Comment: Thank you, I've yet to run into a better tool than AutoIt for this kind of use on Windows, it's brilliant!